# SEOをする時どうすればテーブルやリストを検索結果に表示しますか？

Tags: untagged

最近SEO（検索エンジン最適化）をやっていますが、まだまだ素人です。
なのでお聞きしたいと思います。

検索する時に、リストやテーブルが検索結果に出てくる時があります、例えば：

[image: リスト]

[image: テーブル]

注：写真の内容は私と関係ありません。

このような表示したい時はどうすれば良いですか、ヒントをいただけたらと思います、宜しくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問に貼られた画像にも「強調スニペットについて」と説明リンクが張られています。なぜリンク先を読もうとしないのか理解できません。

リンク先の[Googleの強調スニペットの仕組み](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707?p=featured_snippets&hl=ja-JP&visit_id=637769815313342892-2951351686&rd=1)には

> 強調スニペットは、ユーザーの探している情報が見つけやすくなると判断された場合に表示され、実際にリンクをクリックしたときの内容やページに関する説明を見ることができます。モバイルや音声で検索を行うユーザーに特に便利な機能です。

> 強調スニペットは、ウェブ検索結果から作られます。Google では、あるページが特定の検索リクエストに対してハイライト表示すべきスニペットとして適しているかどうかを、自動システムで判断します。

と説明されています。まずは検索エンジン利用者が有用と感じられるコンテンツを用意し、それがGoogleに認められることです。

その上でどのようにHTMLを記述すればいいかについては[Google 検索での強調スニペットの管理方法](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/featured-snippets?visit_id=637769815313342892-2951351686&rd=1)で説明されています。

---

強調スニペットへの興味の有無に関わらず、Googleの用意している[Google 検索に関するドキュメント](https://developers.google.com/search/docs)に目を通すべきです。

Comment: 確かにおしゃる通りですが、もしすでにコンテンツの質がその基準を超えたとする、スニペットを狙いたい時はどうすれば良いですか。注意点や修正すべきところとかありますか。